# Counting entries on association table and inject it into a model, using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

### The goal

Count entries on association table and inject it into a model, using Rails (v. 4.1).

### The scenario

There is `game.rb` model:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :genres
end
```

and there is also a `genre.rb` model:

```
class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

In the database, there are three tables: `games`, `genres`, `games_genres` – and `games` is still empty because I'm still developing `genres` area. So, `genres`' table is like following:

```
+----+-----------+
| id | name      |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | Action    |
|  2 | RPG       |
+----+-----------+
```

And this is `games_genres` table:

```
+----+--- -----+----------+
| id | game_id | genre_id |
+----+---------+----------+
|  1 |       1 |        1 |
|  2 |       1 |        2 |
|  3 |       2 |        1 |
+----+---------+----------+
```

### The problem

My application has an API and to retreive `genres`, I'm doing this way:

```
class API::V1::TargetsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render json: Genre.all.to_json
  end
end
```

The output is something like this:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Action'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'RPG'
  }
]
```

But, I want to *inject* the count of how many products has each genre. The query is simple:

```
SELECT COUNT(genre_id) AS products_quantity FROM game_genres
```

So, how can I *inject* `products_quantity` <sup>see above's query</sup> within `Genre` model? Something to get the JSON's output like this:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Action',
    products_quantity: 2
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'RPG',
    products_quantity: 1
  }
]
```

Comment: Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294219/how-can-i-include-association-count-in-activerecord-query-so-that-it-doesnt-per.  Might be something like what you need.

Comment: I do believe you might have to change the `has_and_belongs_to_many` into a standard `has_many through` and `belongs_to` setup though. Checkout http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#detailed-association-reference

Comment: I think your comment is being useful to my case, but I don't want to work with `games_genres` directly, like `has_many :through` suggests. Let me ask, `count_cache` is a bad thing to make me change the rules?

Comment: While you can generally go with `has_and_belongs_to_many` you aren't hurting anything by going with a `has_many through` it just gives you the option to interact with the join table if you would like to in the future.

Comment: I'm going with @BartJedrocha 's answer because he introduced me rabl – which is very useful and robust. Anyway, thank you to you too, m8.

Comment: Not a problem, Rabl is powerful it seems like. I also have yet to use it. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `method` option to the `to_json` method. Thus you can define a `product_quantity` method on your `Genre` model

```
def product_quantity
  game_genres.count
end
```

and then have it included in the `to_json` call.

```
class API::V1::TargetsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render json: Genre.all.to_json(methods: :product_quantity)
  end
end
```

While the above will work, I would suggest you use something more robust like [rabl](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) to handle JSON responses.

Comment: Do you think this way is better than [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294219/how-can-i-include-association-count-in-activerecord-query-so-that-it-doesnt-per), with `count_cache`? If so, why?

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge Using `counter_cache` is preferred as it won't require a separate call to the database to fetch the counts.